# 2.1 Syntax not Working in 2.2. Update child record via parent class

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orientdb2.2

Hello OrientDB followers,

I have an issue that has been taking up more of my time than i would like to spend on.

In 2.1, I was able to ***update a parent record and child record from a single command or just the child record via an update of the parent class***. However, **in 2.2, it does not work**.. I have used the same exact syntax in both.

Take the following sample data set

```
create class Users
create property Users.username
create property Users.password

create class Devices
create property Devices.name

insert into Users (username, password) values('johndoe','randompassword')

  update users add Devices = [{
            "@type": "d",
            "@class": "Devices",
            "name": "Note 7"
        }]
```

lets say that the Device class record that we just inserted ended up with an rid of #13:0

In version **2.1**, I am able to execute the following syntax below, in order to update the parent and the child record. **It works perfect**

```
  update users set username = 'johndoethesenior', Devices = [{
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid":   #14:0,
            "@version":1,
            "@class": "Devices",
            "name": "Note 8"
        }] where username = 'johndoe'
```

There lies my issue. In 2.1 it works perfectly. However, **in 2.2, even though i do not get an error and it shows the record as updated, the name on the Devices record does not change from Note 7 to Note 8.**

The change on the parent record, does go through and changes from johndoe to johndoethesenior.

I looked through the release notes and changes of 2.1 -> 2.2 and could not find any references to this.

Did i discover a bug, or am I overlooking something that changed in the orient architecture after 2.2 release.

Last note, I have tried this on at least 4 versions of 2.2, on different servers and deployments. All have the same behavior.

Any guidance in the matter would be truly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I have tested your queries on both versions affected and reproduced the problem, working on alternative query as workaround.

Comment: Can you open an issue for this bug?

Comment: Yes.Thanks, if you find a workaround. Please let me know, would really appreciate it. Will be submitting this as a bug today.

Comment: I added to open issues. Can you please confirm it on the bug submission.   https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6729

Answer (score 0):

As work - around you can try with this easy JS function:

```
var g = orient.getGraph();
var b = g.command("sql","update users set username = '"+newUserName+"' where username = '"+userName+"'");
var c = g.command("sql","update devices set name = '"+newDeviceName+"' where name = '"+deviceName+"'");
```

This is how you call it in studio:

```
select newUpdate("new value of class users","value to replace of class users","new value of class devices","value to replace of class devices")
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could use the [SQL BATCH](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-batch.html).

I used your structure
[image]

I used this sql batch command

```
begin 
let $a= update users set username="johndoethesenior" return after $current.Devices.@rid where username="johndoe"
let $b = update $a.value set name="Note 8" return after $current.@rid 
commit
return [$a.size(),$b.size()]
```

[image: enter code here]

and I got

[image]

Hope it helps.